# Rails CRUD route and controller method best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

CRUD stands for Create, Read, Update, Delete. That's four methods (or five if you distinguish between viewing one record and viewing all records). In Rails, it seems like the canonical way to handle CRUD involves seven methods. For instance, making routes for an Order object using the `resources :orders` shorthand generates the following seven routes:

- index
- new
- create
- show
- edit
- update
- destroy

Here's the source of my confusion. What's the point of having separate actions/routes for `new`/`create` and `edit`/`update`? What is the benefit of having separate actions for viewing the page vs. creating the record in the database? I understand *how* it is done in Rails, e.g.:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    render
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
      redirect_to @order, notice: 'Successfully created an order.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Before working with Rails, I used Yii (PHP), which had a built-in CRUD generator that generated code like this (translated to Rails):

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def create

    if request.method == "POST"
      @order = Order.new(order_params)
      if @order.save
        redirct_to @order, notice: 'Successfully created an order.'
      end
    else
      @order = Order.new
    end

    render 

  end
end
```

The reason I prefer this pattern is because it avoids having to render a template for a different controller action. In the first code example, the user goes to `orders/new` and posts to `orders/create`. If validation fails, the user is still stuck at `orders/create` but viewing the template for `orders/new`. This might confuse the user, and it also seems to defeat the whole idea of having separate actions for viewing a page vs. creating a record in the database. And if you redirect to `orders/new` rather than using `render :new` then you lose all your validation error messages.

I find myself subconsciously slipping back to the Yii way in my Rails code. Can anyone explain why the standard way is advantageous? Are there any problems I am going to run into if I deviate from the canonical Rails pattern?

StackOverflow is warning me that the question is subjective and likely to be closed, so let me clarify. I am not trying to debate Rails vs. Yii or determine the best theoretical way to organize CRUD code. I want to know if there is anything about Rails that will break if I deviate from the canonical Rails way of handling CRUD.

Comment: I don't know if it will give out any errors but one of the most used phrases in Ruby On Rails development is 'Convention over Configuration' ... I don't think it's very smart to change this process as it will become harder to get help once you get stuck and you will make it harder for other people to read your code/collaborate with you.

Comment: i think canonical Rails way is intended for separation of concern to help someone who just started writing web-apps in general .. more like how web applications are built and works in general .. to just scaffold your resource and get the server up and running .. and as you get along adding features to your app .. you tend to write custom routes and skew away from canonical way of doing things in rails .. rails gives much flexibility to do that and i think it's okay to do that .. however, i am no expert on this and i'm looking forward to more insightful answers on this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple explanation is:

> because that's how God and DHH intended it.

The Rails CRUD conventions are quite pragmatic and allow you to avoid many pitfalls related to browser caching and security.

Lets take one example:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private 
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Here we have
two separate routes `GET /users/new` and `POST /users`.

The first route is idempotent - it should look the same for any visitor and can be cached. The second is not - it should show the result of creating or attempting to create a resource.

When a user visits `/users/new` we POST the form to a different URI. That avoids history issues in the client.

We also render the form in the same request cycle if the input is invalid. This avoids the security issues that would arise if we tried to pass the form data back in redirect to `/users/new` and lets us return the semantically correct response code instead of a redirect.

It also ensures that our application is stateless in the restful sense since the previous action does not influence what we see if we were to visit `/users/new`.

On an architecture level, it allows you to leverage convention over configuration. You can just do:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

And it will render `views/users/new.html.erb` because Rails can derive that the new action should render the new template. Having each controller action perform one single task is far better from a design and testing standpoint as it eliminates the need to test two separate code paths in the same method.

Comment: The biggest problem with deviating would be that no one will hire you. Rails is extremely convention driven and opinionated. And a developer who actively skirts all the conventions which make rails fun and productive is not very attractive.

Comment: I personally find the YII methodology plain stupid from a MVC design standpoint. Its the routing component in the stacks job to determine what action should be called by matching the request method. Not something that should be repeated all over your controllers.